# Texture don't seem to match source:

Tags: texturing

[image: screenie]This is a purchased, imported .obj with its material/textures. Can't find a way to apply the textures although they appear on the menu. This is probably elementary but can't find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: So your question is how to apply a texture to a material?

Comment: Do you want to render with Blender Render engine? It's not the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I would like to try with internal first, if it's possible, before playing with the nodes. And this is the best I now get... Guess it's a little better.[![with applied texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8CdC.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8CdC.jpg)